# Mongo aggregate: apply currency rate for a dynamic conditional

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

Let's say I have a exchange rate API: https://exchange-rate.com/summaries return a list of currency

```
[
  {market: 'ETH-USD', lastPrice: 4000}
  {market: 'BTC-USD', lastPrice: 38000}
  {market: 'USDT-USD', lastPrice: 1.01}
]
```

My **offers collection** store mix currencies each document

```
[
  {_id: 1, currency: 'ETH', amount: 1}
  {_id: 2, currency: 'BTC', amount: 0.5}
  {_id: 3, currency: 'USDT', amount: 2000}
]
```

I want to get min or max amount base on currency rate to show for client. For example

```
[
  min: {_id: 3, currency: 'USDT', amount: 2000}
]
```

```
[
  max: {_id: 2, currency: 'BTC', amount: 0.5}
]
```

How can I apply dynamic exchange rate every time I want to aggregate them?

Comment: Can you explain about dynamic exchange rate use case with sample?

Comment: I mean the exchange rate always change following crypto market. In above example real value of each offer to USD is:

`[
  {_id: 1, currency: 'ETH', amount: 1, valueInUSD: 4000}
  {_id: 2, currency: 'BTC', amount: 0.5, valueInUSD: 19000}
  {_id: 3, currency: 'USDT', amount: 2000, valueInUSD: 2020}
]`

So offer with BTC is on highest price, and Offer with USDT is on lowest price

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
db.offers.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "exchange",
      let: {currency: "$currency"},
      pipeline: [
        {
          $addFields: {"currencies": {$split: ["$market", "-"]}}
        },
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {$eq: ["$$currency", {$arrayElemAt: ["$currencies", 0]}]}
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {lastPrice: 1, _id: 0}
        }
      ],
      as: "exchange"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      amount: 1,
      currency: 1,
      exchangeRatio: {
        $cond: [{$gt: [{$size: "$exchange"}, 0]},
          {$arrayElemAt: ["$exchange", 0]},
          {"lastPrice": 1}
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      amount: 1,
      currency: 1,
      currentValUSD: {"$multiply": ["$amount", "$exchangeRatio.lastPrice"]}
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {currentValUSD: sortType} // sortType value is 1 or -1
  },
  {
    $limit: 1
  },
  {
    $unset: "currentValUSD"
  }
])
```

As you can see [on this playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/z2k_QkyBD7s).

The `$lookup` pipeline splits the currencies string on the `exchange` collection and filter the one `exchange` document that its first part of the string is the offer's `currency`. The second step is calculating the `exchangeRatio` and using `1` if the offer's currency is `USD`. The next step is calculating the common ground of `currentValUSD` and now all is left is to `$sort`, `$limit`, and format, according to your needs.

Comment: The exchange rate is from a API not from a table so I am trying to convert the first aggregate from $lookup to another aggregation. I will update the last result for you